# Flask convert Case route to File Path

Tags: javascript, python, api, flask, routes

I'm using flask as my backend in a ReactApp, and I have a def written to take a search keyword and look for it in the Flask Database and return a case's details and write a case tree with that data.

I want to change that code to look for the def. in such a way that it creates the same case tree but instead look for the keyword in the file path, rather than flask database.

Here's the Def.

```
@case.route('/case-tree', methods=["GET", "POST"])
@token_required
def case_tree():
    """
    Route that would give sub-directories and
    files that reside inside a give case.
    """

    # Get case_name
    try:
        req = request.get_json()
        case_name = req['case_name']

    # Throw Error if case_name is not provided
    except Exception as e:
        response = {
            "success": False,
            "message": "Please Provide A Case Name."
        }
        return make_response(jsonify(response)), 422

    # Find case with given name
    case = Case.query.filter_by(case_name=case_name).first()

    # Check if case with given name exists or not
    if not case:
        response = {
            "success": False,
            "message": "Case not found."
        }
        return make_response(jsonify(response)), 404

    # absolute path of case
    case_path = case.data_path

    # get details of extractor
    extractor_detail = extractor_schema.dump(case.extractor)

    # dump case
    case_json = case_schema.dump(case)

    # attach extractor detail with case_json
    case_json['extractor_detail'] = extractor_detail

    # get directory-tree with given case_name
    try:
        directory_tree = {}
        getDirectoryTree(tree=directory_tree,
                         rootDirectory=case_path, rootDirectoryName=case_name)

        # create resposne
        response = {
            "success": True,
            "message": "Tree Fetched.",
            "case": case_json,
            "tree": json.dumps(directory_tree),
        }
        return make_response(jsonify(response)), 200

    # Response if something went wrong.
    except Exception as e:
        response = {
            "success": False,
            "message": "something went wrong."
        }
        return make_response(jsonify(response)), 500
```

I also have this code for reference that looks for a keyword and returns the file path but doesn't create a case tree.

```
@keyword.route('/search/tags', methods=['POST'])
def searchtags():
    try:
        req = request.get_json()

        tags = str(req['tags'])
        tags = tags.split(',')

    except Exception as e:

        print(e)

        return 'Please provide tags', 400

    caselisttags = searchtag(tags) #searchtags defined in code snippet below

    if caselisttags:
        '''
            If cases found with the desired tags.
        '''
        return jsonify(caselisttags)

    else:
        response = {
            "success": False,
            "message": "No case found with this tag"
        }
    return make_response(jsonify(response)), 404
```

```
def searchtag(tags):
    '''
    searchtag() search the case tags which are set while extracting the case
    '''
    case_list_tags = []

    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(cases_data_path):

        if subdir[-6:] == "report":

            for filename in files:

                filepath = os.sep.join([subdir, filename])
                

                if filepath.endswith(".txt"):

                    open_path_file = open(filepath, "r", encoding="UTF-8")

                    read_path_file = open_path_file.read()

                    '''
                        tags_bool stores bool if tags are present or not
                    '''
                    tags_bool = all(ele in read_path_file for ele in tags)
                    open_path_file.close()

                    if tags_bool:

                        '''
                            if tag found in report
                        '''

                        case_list_tags.append(os.path.dirname(
                            os.path.dirname(filepath)))

    return case_list_tags
```

What I need is to change the `def case_tree()` such that looks for the keyword in the File directory instead of looking through the flask database, similar to `def searchtags()`.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: what is the problem? Do you get error? Show it in question (not in comments) as text. Do you get wrong result? Show this result in question, and show expected result. We can't run your code and we can't read in your mind - you have to describe all details in question.

Comment: There is no error message. I'm working on this code, written by someone else and I'm having trouble trying to understand it and changing it. I have added more informaition at the end of the question to describe it better.

Comment: did you run flask code in console/terminal to see error messages? We can't run this code so we can't see what can make problem - so I can only suggest (again) to use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables. And of course it needs to run flask code in console/terminal to see printed data. BTW: and you could use `console.log()` in browser to see what you get in JavaScript.